# Migration error PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I getting the error while running the migration after creating fresh db.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :phone
  has_many :projects
  has_many :items

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  scope :find_by_fullname, -> (fullname) { 
    self.all
        .select{ |u| u if u.full_name.parameterize == fullname}
        .first }

end
```

Error is getting by the scope find_by_fullname ,
The error is

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
```

Please anyone suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist

The error says that you don't have `"users"` table in your database.

Which means you forgot to run the migrations, run the following command to run the migration

```
rake db:migrate

# OR

bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Please read question carefully, I am running fresh migration after creating fresh db. I know about the current error, but first time it happening, I think  the rake db:migrate is loading the modal first, where the code(scope) puted for users thats why. Don't know where is the issue.

Comment: In that case, check if you have any migration where you are firing a query on any `model`

Comment: If possible you can move that migration down by changing the timestamp or moving the migration for users table up

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, when doing `rake db:migrate` on a new clean server, I was getting:

```
Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "nodes" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"nodes"'::regclass
```

It turned out I was calling `Node.find(...)` in one of my `config/initializers`. That works fine when you've already got a migrated database, but on a new server it causes a chicken-and-egg problem: `rake` crashes before it can run the migrations.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you have not run migration that's why `users` table in not exist your database.

Try to run migration by running this command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: This is the same solution already provided in Deepak's answer.

Comment: Please read question carefully, I am running fresh migration after creating fresh db. I know about the current error, but first time it happening, I think  the rake db:migrate is loading the modal first, where the code(scope) puted for users thats why. Don't know where is the issue.